# Does high level management need to sign all policies?

Tags: company-policy

I am implementing new policies in my workplace. I know the CEO must sign the legally required policies but does he also have to sign all the others? 
Are policies considered to be void if they are not signed?

Comment: Ironically, that depends on your company's policy. Different companies require different levels of approval for implementing policies.  And it will depend on the number of people it will impact, and whether the policy is mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can't really address questions of legality -- that would depend on jurisdiction and existing company policies -- but it looks like your core question is really "do I need to get the CEO to sign everything?", so let me offer an answer to that.

In a company of any size, it will become impractical for any one person to personally handle all policies.  This is why companies have layers of management and chains of command.  The CEO doesn't need to personally sign your policy on how to fill out timesheets if he *authorizes you to determine that*.  The CEO is ultimately accountable for what happens in his organization, but for matters that he doesn't need to personally handle (for business or legal reasons) he should delegate authority and get out of the way.

If there is a problem with your policies, people may escalate their complaints up the chain to the CEO.  If you anticipate issues with a policy you're considering, you would be wise to discuss it with your manager before you proceed, so that when those complaints come they won't come as a surprise (and you'll know where those above you stand).